# how to step through a list and accumulate a integer value telling how many times an element based on it's position in list was seen

Tags: python, list, for-loop, counter

I'm trying to see how many times an element has been seen in a list

for instance:

```
list = [125,130,140,123,125,140,130,140]
```

I want to figure out perhaps how many times the element in position 0 (here, 125) was seen in the list, and accumulate the value with a counter. For the element in position 0, I would want to yield the int, 2.

Comment: what is wrong with `your_list.count(your_list[0])`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, a complex machinery is unnecessary:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 2]
>>> l.count(l[1])
2
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
my_list = [125,130,140,123,125,140,130,140]
Counter(my_list)
```

Output:

```
Counter({140: 3, 130: 2, 125: 2, 123: 1})
```

Comment: How is this efficient compared to `list.count`(runs at C speed) when all OP needs is count of one item?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary counter is more efficient in counting multiple elements

Comment: OP never asked for count of all items.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary i just given idea, that you can achieve more

Comment: A bad idea for this question and inefficient too.

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehension and `len`:

```
count = len([l for l in list if l == list[n]])
```

where `n` is the index of the item you are counting.

Answer (score 0):

You could store them in a dictionary with a dict comprehension (which works exactly like list comprehensions):

```
l = [125,130,140,123,125,140,130,140]
counts = {x : l.count(x) for x in l}
```

Also, it is bad practice to name your list "list".  This will conflict with the built-in list function in Python.

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo(pos, values):
    counter = 0
    element_to_find = values[pos]
    for element in values:
        if element == element_to_find:
            counter += 1
    return counter
```